# Why do some Micro-USB plugs have these two slits/springs on one side and some don't?

Tags: usb

Just so you understand what i'm talking about, here is a regular plug without those "slits" (I don't know what to call them):

[image]

And here is a plug with them:

[image]

I only noticed this diefference because my phone (Samsung Galaxy s2+) doesn't work very well with the first kind. What makes things difficult is that nobody seems to know about this - not my friends, not the clerk at the store, no one - so it makes it hard to buy the correct micro-USB cables that will work with my phone.

So - what is the deal here? Are those things just something that some manufacturers decided to add to their products? (The official USB diagrams don't show the slits).

Comment: Are you referring to the cutouts in the top of the metal band that create two pressure fingers?

Comment: They're to enhance contact of the plug's shield with the receptacle's ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were made when they updated the plugs with newer versions. Although the idea is that when you plug them in, it will "click" in place, the newer versions are slightly different in the sense that they're longer, which allows more current to go through. They're somewhat backwards compatible, in the sense that they will fit, but stick out, but the other way around, it won't work.

And the version of course is the USB version. A Micro USB v1.0 type c, is different than a Micro USB v2.0 type c. Etc.